# Trying to have admin user create other users, but it keeps taking me to Edit User after submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I was following Tony Amoyal's setup for authentication using Devise/cancan and only allowing an admin to create/register new users. I didn't follow him exactly because there is no need for users to have multiple roles in this application, but for the most  part I used exactly what he suggested.

It mostly works, but the biggest issue I am having right now is when I try to create a new user and submit it on the register form, it immediately complains, takes me to Devise's edit registration form and complains about the :current_password field not being filled in.   If I fill anything in at that point, it will update MY user, not the one I was trying to register.

Any help to get it to actually create the user instead of requesting more changes would be appreciated.

*#controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb*

```
    class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      before_filter :check_permissions, :only => [:new, :create, :cancel]
      skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication

      def check_permissions
        authorize! :create, resource
      end
    end
```

*#controllers/users_controller.rb*

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      load_and_authorize_resource :except =>[:create]
      ...
      def new
        respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render :json => @user }   
          format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
          format.html
        end
      end
      ...

      def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])

        if @user.save
          respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render :json => @user.to_json, :status => 200 }
            format.xml  { head :ok }
            format.html { redirect_to :action => :index }
          end
       else
         respond_to do |format|
           format.json { render :text => "Could not create user", :status => :unprocessable_entity } # placeholder
           format.xml  { head :ok }
           format.html { render :action => :new, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
         end
       end
     end
   end
```

*#views/users/new.html.haml*

```
    = simple_form_for(@user, :method => :put, :html => {  :class=>'form-horizontal' }) do |f|
  %fieldset
    %legend
      = f.input :first_name
      = f.input :last_name
          = f.input :email
          = f.input :password
          = f.input :password_confirmation

       .form-actions
         = f.submit 'Register', :class => 'btn btn-primary'
         = link_to 'Back', :back, :class => 'btn'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this problem by giving devise a path_prefix which would ensure this process is using my UsersController.